# Glassfish & Apache

Tags: apache, dns, glassfish

I want to "combine" my existing apache with a fresh glassfish installation. Apache is running at port 80 and glassfish's deploy artifact is listening on 8080.

Glassfish is installed with X Server particular user and developer rights for "userX". Apache runs with permissions of "www-data" by default.

Is there any chance to link all the data of a particular subdomain like "glassfish.localhost" internally from port 80 to 8080 in a way the user won't realize that redirecting?

As I realized there is also a problem with permission & credentials.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure an AJP connector between Glassfish and Apache using Apache mod_jk plugin.

By default glassfish has an AJP connector on port 8009, so you need to configure apache with a jk worker using the same port, and set a virtual host "glassfish.yourdomain.ext" using this worker.

The steps are :

1- install mod_jk plugin on apache and configure an AJP worker `ajpworker` using a
    `worker.properties` file containing :

```
worker.list=ajpworker
worker.ajpworker.type=ajp13
worker.ajpworker.host=localhost
worker.ajpworker.port=8009
```

2- configure apache to load mod_jk with the worker.properties file above, and redirect your subdomain to `ajpworker` by definig a virtual host :

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/workers.properties
JkLogFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    info
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName yourdomain.ext
        JkMount / ajpworker
        JkMount /* ajpworker
</VirtualHost>
```

3- Create a virtual host with your subdomain in glassfish (can be done on glassfish administration page)

Note that users won't be redirected to port 8080, the traffic will go trough port 80, Apache acting as a intermediate between the user and glassfish. You can even close HTTP 8080 listener on glassfish, the data between glassfish and apache will use the AJP 8009 port.

Comment: Well, I will check& vote it this weekend. Thanks for your hint!